# How to specify a Moment.js object annotation in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

I'm currently learning Flow by applying it to an existing project and looking to annotate function parameters as a Moment.JS objects.

Using [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/) I was able to install a library definition for Moment.JS which appears to have the type I'm looking for:

```
declare class moment$Moment {
  static ISO_8601: string;
  static (string?: string, format?: string|Array<string>, locale?: string, strict?: bool): moment$Moment;
  static (initDate: ?Object|number|Date|Array<number>|moment$Moment|string): moment$Moment;
  static unix(seconds: number): moment$Moment;
  static utc(): moment$Moment;
  ...
```

However when I try to annotate function parameters as Moment.JS objects, Flow fails to recognize them as such. In the following function `startDate` and `endDate` are Moment.JS date objects.

```
const filterByDateWhereClause = (startDate: Moment, endDate: Moment): string => {...};
```

Flow gives the following error:

```
const filterByDateWhereClause = (startDate: Moment, endDate: Moment): string =>
                                                 ^^^^^^ identifier `Moment`. Could not resolve name
```

Is this even possible with Flow? Or do I need to duplicate the `type` for the Moment.JS object identical to the one in the library definition provided by flow-type? I'd prefer not to do this as the libdef is fairly lengthy.

For example:

```
declare class Moment {
  static ISO_8601: string;
  static (string?: string, format?: string|Array<string>, locale?: string, strict?: bool): moment$Moment;
  static (initDate: ?Object|number|Date|Array<number>|moment$Moment|string): moment$Moment;
  static unix(seconds: number): moment$Moment;
  static utc(): moment$Moment;
  ...

const filterByDateWhereClause = (startDate: Moment, endDate: Moment): string => {...};
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are three ways to get the type you want.

If your file already require's `moment` as a module you should be able to use that type

```
import moment from 'moment';

const filterByDateWhereClause = (startDate: moment, endDate: moment): string => {...};
```

or if you don't use the source but just the type within your file.

```
import type Moment from 'moment';

const filterByDateWhereClause = (startDate: Moment, endDate: Moment): string => {...};
```

You can do this because that's what the libdef specifies as the module export:
https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/7822da72587078a4b8e0f2b56746d0da41a3ddde/definitions/npm/moment_v2.x.x/flow_v0.34.x-/moment_v2.x.x.js#L233

Alternatively, it looks like that libdef declares a type `moment$Moment` in the global namespace too so you can use that.

```
const filterByDateWhereClause = (startDate: moment$Moment, endDate: moment$Moment): string => {...};
```

I wouldn't recommend the global usage though since it's less explicit where the type is coming from.

Comment: The `moment$Moment` won't work for me, perhaps because I'm using Webpack so there's no global namespace? The two import methods worked.

Comment: Webpack shouldn't have an effect on how flow runs -- I'm not sure why the global type isn't working for you but it's fine because you shouldn't really use it...

In the CONTRIBUTING.md doc for flow-typed, it tells libdef authors to prefix globals that aren't meant to be global: (https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/316320bf2cbc48a9447e053272a5c113e6e26a8c/CONTRIBUTING.md#prefix-global-variables-that-arent-really-meant-to-be-global), so you shouldn't be using that anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if creating a subclass from the moment object solves this problem:

```
import moment from 'moment';

class Moment extends moment {}

const filterByDateWhereClause = (startDate: Moment, endDate: Moment): string => {...};
```

Still interested to know if this the correct way to annotate a Moment.JS object however.